# Where should I keep connectiong string in distributed (SOA) architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-config, connection-string, app-config

In my application I have the following projects:

1. MVC (containing reference of WCF)
2. WCF service AS BAL (containing reference of DAL)
3. DAL

Where should I keep the connection string, so it will be accessible to the DAL?

In which project's configuration file; would it be in the ASP.NET MVC and then available to DAL, or should I have to explicitly put the connection string into the DAL project's configuration file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your connection string in your WCF service as I believe your MVC won't be connecting directly to database, it would be using WCF service to fetch data.

I would suggest to put connection string in WCF service.

Comment: @user3711357 if this answered your query please also up vote it